# Как растянуть background ? Чтоб он был по размерам самого spinner

Tags: android, xml

Проблема в том, что я не могу растянуть полностью колокольчик уведомлений по размеру самого Spinner. Я начинающий разработчик и это мой личный проект. Я решил сделать уведомления в виде Spinner. Буду благодарен если дадите совет, как лучше это реализовать(изменить) это.

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/NotificationSpinner"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_bell"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/UserButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/ActivePoints"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/UserButton"
         />
```

Выглядит он так:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wdmm.png

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

С учетом того что было на картинке в плане контекста, то я могу предложить изменить размер фоновой картинки в коде, то есть у вас у спиннера судя по всему размер:

```
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="68dp"
```

у drawable картинки в коде будут такие параметры:

```
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
```

их нужно изменить согласно размеру спиннера и должно сработать. Если я все-таки не угадал что именно вам нужно, то добавьте немного больше инфы :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/umutbaiev/1709edd2d9ead8fbec83a2221d983528

Comment: Не помогло. Это код картинки.

Comment: вам нужно на весь спиннер растянуть картинку или вместо треугольника добавить? просто если на весь спиннер растянуть, то есть вероятность неудачи)

Comment: прост в приложение он не на своем месте стоит из за того что границы и сама картинка разные

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/FkE5YXy0eSc-oQ